# How to list work history on job application

Tags: applications

The job application I am looking at is asking me to list my last three employers.

I worked for a school district last year and I worked at two schools. One of the schools was .3 and one was .5. I was under one contract for both of these schools that equaled .8. I really want to split these jobs up and list them as two separate jobs. Would it be ok to list them as two separate jobs/employers, or since I worked for one school district, would I have to list it as one job even though I worked at two different schools?

Edit: Also, I work for both Uber and Lyft in my free time. I would like to list at least one of them- Uber or Lyft- as a previous employer. Would this be ok to do? I understand I’m an independent contractor/ self- employed with Uber and Lyft but just curious if this would be ok to do.

Comment reply: it was one paycheck from the school district.

Comment: Did you get separate paychecks for the two jobs, or only one?

Comment: What are these numbers? Full time equivalents? Please [edit] that in.

Comment: " I would like to list at least one of them- Uber or Lyft- as a previous employer" - is that in any way relevant to the position that you are applying for? I might be tempted to just list the two school jobs. I doubt that they would penalize you for not having three ***relevant*** previous jobs, where "relevant" is the operative word.

Comment: Why do you want to split the two school jobs? You were under contract with the district and paid by the district - you had one job, you worked for the school district. And that's what will come up when your references and work history are independently checked.

Answer (score 1):

> since I worked for one school district, would I have to list it as one job even though I worked at two different schools?

I have a friend who is also a teacher. It appears that they list their roles for different schools as two separate jobs, even though both positions were for the same school district. It is important to note that there were different classes they taught (agriculture & business versus science) for the respective schools.

> I work for both Uber and Lyft in my free time. I would like to list at least one of them- Uber or Lyft- as a previous employer. Would this be ok to do?

I don't imagine there would be anything wrong with listing these as well. After all, they are apart of your work history.

`I would always weigh the pros and cons of listing a role that is not in your industry (or recent)`

For instance, I would not list the fact that I used to work for a pharmacy for future software roles I apply for since they are not related, unless the software job was related to pharmacy etc., thus giving me unique experience other candidates probably do not have. Anything on your resume that doesn't add a large amount of value is just noise.

Answer (score 0):

If they were different jobs then list them separately.

Different jobs means some of the following were different:

- Roles and responsibilities
- Skills and experience needed
- Supervisors
- Co-workers

To make it clear that they were different jobs, on each one don’t just list the school district as your employer, include the school name.

This assumes that there are not strict rules which govern how you apply for jobs in your location.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply list the following? (unless there are specific requirements for schools regarding this matter)

**- professional work experience**(assuming,those job titles are your education / profession; if not state just "work experience") :

start-date, end-date, school district, school A, job title

start-date, end-date, school district, school B, job title

**- other work experience:**

start-date, end-date, uber, job title

start-date, end-date, Lyft, job title

*Instead of dates you could also just say x months instead and maybe the year.*